Как сохранить данные пользователя Chrome в процессе перезапуска Flutter Web приложения?
Пишу web приложение на Flutter с авторизацией OAuth2. При перезапуске Chrome в режиме дебага пароль в профиле пользователя не запоминается и каждый раз вводить пароль не хочется.
Помогло решение с основного SO.
Т.е. необходимо проделать следующее:

Перейти в PROJECT_ROOT\.dart_tool\chrome-device. Если папки .dart-tool или chrome-device не существуют, то
достаточно запустить проект в Chrome.
Внутри PROJECT_ROOT\.dart_tool\chrome-device должна быть папка Default. Папку Deafult со всем содержимым
необходимо скопировать в новую папку, в которой будут хранится профили пользователя для тестирования работы flutter
приложения. К примеру, C:\Users\MyUser\AndroidStudioProjects\FlutterWebProfiles.
Закрыть Android Studio
Перейти в папку с установленным Flutter по пути flutter\bin\cache и удалить файл flutter_tools.stamp.
Перейти в flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web и открыть файл chrome.dart
Изменить строку --user-data-dir=${userDataDir.path} на --user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AndroidStudioProjects\\FlutterWebProfiles

Но данное решение обладает одним недостатком, flutter upgrade перезаписывает файл chrome.dart и приходится повторять шаги с 4 по 6.
Вроде как должен работать запуск Chrome в дебаг режиме с аргументом --web-browser-flag "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AndroidStudioProjects\\FlutterWebProfiles". Но мне не удалось сохранить пароли используя этот аргумент. Аргумент задаю в Android Studio launch configuration.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать сохранение паролей в Chrome в процессе перезапуска в дебаг режиме.
